# How to set first letter to upperCase on button click

Tags: javascript

When i click button and it appears on web-page i want to do the first letter toUpperCase(); But i don't know how to it properly. I made it like this:

```
function toUpper() {
            arr.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr.slice(1);
 }
```

But this seems not correct, please explain how to do it right way?

```
    <input type="text" id="inp">
    <button class="btn">Push to array</button>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    <br><br>
    <div id="list"></div>

<script>

var inp = document.getElementById("inp");
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var list = document.querySelector('#list');
var del = document.querySelector(".delete");
var arr = [];

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var valInp = inp.value; 
  if (valInp === '') { return; }
  arr.push(valInp);
  inp.value = "";
  list.innerHTML = arr.join("<br>").trim();

    function toUpper() {
        arr.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr.slice(1);
    }
});

 del.addEventListener('click', function(){
    arr.pop();
    list.innerHTML = arr.join("<br>").trim();   
});

</script>
```

Comment: Where did you want to call that `toUpper`? Also, array shouldn't have `charAt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to call that `toUpper` somewhere, currently you just keep define it in that click event handler. It's better to define it out of that event handler because it can be reused again and again.
2. You should expect that `toUpper` function to accept an `string`(as it should do something to a `string`, but not on `arr` which is an `array`), then return a new string that convert first char to its uppercase.
3. Push the transformed string to that array, and it's done.

```js
var inp = document.getElementById("inp");
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var list = document.querySelector('#list');
var del = document.querySelector(".delete");
var arr = [];

// Move the function out, as it can be reused.
// Input is a string, and you need to return the result of the toUppered string.
function toUpper(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var valInp = inp.value; 
  if (valInp === '') { return; }
  
  // Push the toUppered string into array.
  arr.push(toUpper(valInp));
  inp.value = "";
  list.innerHTML = arr.join("<br>").trim();
});

 del.addEventListener('click', function(){
    arr.pop();
    list.innerHTML = arr.join("<br>").trim();   
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp">
    <button class="btn">Push to array</button>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    <br><br>
    <div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: Could you "please explain how to do it right way" as well?

Comment: Yep, I've already appended some explain and comments in code as well, hope it clears the idea more.

Comment: @fuyushimoya Thank You for a great explanation.